# Add columns to sqlalchemy query's SELECT clause

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a base query that I would like to customize with different select clauses depending on a condition.  Essentially

```
engine = create_engine(…)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
    
base_query = session.query(Employees.id).\
                     filter(Employees.years_service>5)

if need_name:
    Add a select clause for the name field

if need_birthday:
    Add a select clause for birthday
```

…except the filter criteria are much more complicated so I’d rather not just create duplicate queries.

When I want to add additional filter criteria, I can do this kind of decoration by just saying something like:

```
if years_service_max_needed:
    base_query.filter(Employees.years_service<10)
```

but I can’t find a query object method that would allow me to add additional select statements.

Is there a way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with [Query.add_columns](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.add_columns):

> Add one or more column expressions to the list of result columns to be returned.

```
q = session.query(Employees.id)

q = q.add_columns(Employees.name, Employees.years_service)

for row in q:
    print(row)
```